# How to execute sql or query for each row

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I wanted to make a SQL server 2008 script that restores multiple backup files in a folder in one go. The script is made for one file. I want to execute this script in a loop and load all the files in that directory. How do I do this in a simple way.

This is the code for getting the filenames in a folder -

```
EXEC xp_dirtree N'C:\', 10, 1
```

This is what my backup sql looks like -

```
DECLARE some variables
DECLARE @sql varchar(max)
SET the variables
SET @sql = dynamic sql based on above variables.
exec sp_executesql @sql
```

How do I make a simple loop to run my code ? Should I convert my code to function or SP ?

Thanks.

Comment: What's the end goal?  Are you trying to restore the most recent full backup for each user db on the server?

Comment: @DMason - Just trying to restore old backup files after reinstalling sql server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a temp table and store your file list there:

```
CREATE TABLE #FILES(
     Name varchar(200)
,    depth numeric
,    IsFile numeric
)
```

And insert:

```
INSERT INTO #FILES 
   EXEC xp_dirtree N'C:\', 10, 1
```

So you can loop using a cursor:

```
DECLARE @FILENAME AS VARCHAR(200)
DECLARE C CURSOR FOR
    SELECT Name
    FROM #FILES
    WHERE IsFile = 1
OPEN C
FETCH NEXT FROM C INTO @FILENAME
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    DO YOUR STUFF BASED ON FILE

    FETCH NEXT FROM C INTO @FILENAME
END
CLOSE C
DEALLOCATE C
```

Something like that should do the trick